# Disable emailing added non-Google+ user

Tags: email, google-plus

Wasn't aware that adding a non G+ user to (additional) circles would send an email to that contact. Was it always like that? Can I disable this?

Comment: it's been like that since the day G+ was announced.. and this 'trick' was used to jump the beta queue & join G+